# how to convert string to float in for loop in python?

Tags: python, string

I want to calculate the average flow, but I have hard time converting string to float in python.
here is my code in notepad++:

```
import cookielib,urllib2,urllib,string
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
import string

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
total_flow = 0
count = 0
page = opener.open("http://cdec.water.ca.gov/cgi-progs/queryCSV?station_id=vns&sensor_num=20&dur_code=E&start_date=2016-04-14&end_date=2016-04-15&data_wish=View+CSV+Data")
for line in page:
    a=line.split(',')
    b = float(a)
    count+=1
    total_flow= total_flow+b[-1]
# here a=[date,time,flow]; so b[-1] is flow data
ave_flow = total_flow/count 
print ave_flow
```

when I ran this script, I got the error message:

```
b=float(a)
type error: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

however, when I directly converted string to float in python, it worked. I don't know what was going on.

Comment: I think `float` takes a single string, but `a` are multiple strings. So you need another for loop there.

Comment: well after `a = line.split(",")`, `a` is a `list`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Try `b = map(float, a)`

Comment: I have tried b=float(a[-1]) after a=line.split(","), still did not work

Comment: I tried map(float,a), it gave me syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Here a is a list not a string. You should have another for loop to handle each element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

`a = line.split(',')`

This returns a list. That's why you are getting an error.

Comment: maybe in the a list, there is space with the string. do you know how can i use strip to get rid of whitespace and ","? I have tried add b=a.strip() after a= line.split(",")

Answer (score 0):

```
a=line.split(',')
```

a is a list here, try something like:

```
b=float(a[0])
```

Comment: @cricket_007 `b[-1]` attempts to index a float, which isn't possible

Comment: i tried b= float(a[-1]), here a[-1] means last term is the list. But it did not work out

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out. there are some invisible symbol along with string in the list so i can't simply convert string to number.
i changed to 
a=line.strip().split(",")
b=float(a[-1])

and it works.